# Adding fill to an svg

Tags: css, vector, svg

I'm trying to make an icon of a white cloud with a black outline. I'm working off of this path:

```
<svg x="0" y="0" width="512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
  <path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M400,160c-5.312,0-10.562,0.375-15.792,1.125C354.334,120.417,307.188,96,256,96c-51.188,0-98.312,24.417-128.208,65.125c-5.23-0.75-10.48-1.125-15.792-1.125C50.25,160,0,210.25,0,272s50.25,112,112,112c13.688,0,27.084-2.5,39.709-7.333C180.666,401.917,217.5,416,256,416c38.542,0,75.333-14.083,104.291-39.333C372.916,381.5,386.312,384,400,384c61.75,0,112-50.25,112-112S461.75,160,400,160z M400,352c-17.125,0-32.916-5.5-45.938-14.667C330.584,365.624,295.624,384,256,384c-39.625,0-74.584-18.376-98.062-46.667C144.938,346.5,129.125,352,112,352c-44.188,0-80-35.812-80-80c0-44.188,35.812-80,80-80c10.812,0,21.062,2.208,30.438,6.083C163.667,156.667,206.291,128,256,128s92.334,28.667,113.541,70.083C378.938,194.208,389.209,192,400,192c44.188,0,80,35.812,80,80C480,316.188,444.188,352,400,352z"/>
</svg>
```

I can't seem to change the fill, but maybe the path itself leaves an empty center, like a donut.

How can I fill this cloud in white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the path as an outer border plus an inner border, the inside of your path is actually the perceived border of the cloud, and that gets filled with your `#1D1D1B` color.

The simplest solution I can think of is to add one more cloud shape with only the interior border and fill that second cloud with whatever color you want: http://jsfiddle.net/JJJmC/

```
<path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M400,160c-5.312,0-10.562,0.375-15.792,1.125C354.334,120.417,307.188,96,256,96c-51.188,0-98.312,24.417-128.208,65.125c-5.23-0.75-10.48-1.125-15.792-1.125C50.25,160,0,210.25,0,272s50.25,112,112,112c13.688,0,27.084-2.5,39.709-7.333C180.666,401.917,217.5,416,256,416c38.542,0,75.333-14.083,104.291-39.333C372.916,381.5,386.312,384,400,384c61.75,0,112-50.25,112-112S461.75,160,400,160z M400,352c-17.125,0-32.916-5.5-45.938-14.667C330.584,365.624,295.624,384,256,384c-39.625,0-74.584-18.376-98.062-46.667C144.938,346.5,129.125,352,112,352c-44.188,0-80-35.812-80-80c0-44.188,35.812-80,80-80c10.812,0,21.062,2.208,30.438,6.083C163.667,156.667,206.291,128,256,128s92.334,28.667,113.541,70.083C378.938,194.208,389.209,192,400,192c44.188,0,80,35.812,80,80C480,316.188,444.188,352,400,352z"/>
<path fill="Pink" d="M400,352c-17.125,0-32.916-5.5-45.938-14.667C330.584,365.624,295.624,384,256,384c-39.625,0-74.584-18.376-98.062-46.667C144.938,346.5,129.125,352,112,352c-44.188,0-80-35.812-80-80c0-44.188,35.812-80,80-80c10.812,0,21.062,2.208,30.438,6.083C163.667,156.667,206.291,128,256,128s92.334,28.667,113.541,70.083C378.938,194.208,389.209,192,400,192c44.188,0,80,35.812,80,80C480,316.188,444.188,352,400,352z"/>
</svg>
```